# npm run build --mode [.env.mode] not working as expected

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

**What I've done so far:**

I've been trying to setup multiple build modes like `staging`, `testing`, `production` and `development` based on `NODE_ENV=production`. So I'm keeping the respective files in the root of the project folder like:

- .env.production
- .env.staging
- .env.testing
- .env.development

Now, all these files are having

```
NODE_ENV=production
VUE_APP_ENV=<mode>
```

The [document](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#example-staging-mode) that I followed clearly states that,

> `vue-cli-service build --mode staging` builds a **production** app in
>   **staging mode**, using .env, .env.staging and .env.staging.local if they
>   are present.

**Problem:**

As expected, running the command `npm run build --mode staging` is to give a production build with variable as listed in the `.env.staging` file. However, `production` variables are loaded instead of `staging`.

**Ref:**

- https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#example-staging-mode
- https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-build-production-app-with-varying-config/29708

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You need to use the following command

> npm run build -- --mode staging

All arguments before `--` are considered `npm` arguments and arguments after `--` are passed to `vue-cli-service`

Comment: Brilliant! It worked for me! As a side note, I think this behavior is really stupid. I hope they will change it or at least put it into the docs. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem, I figured out my problem was from using a beta version (`3.0.0-beta.9`) of `@vue/cli-service` so changing it to the rc version (`3.0.0-rc.3`) worked. So in my package.json under devDependencies I changed it to `"@vue/cli-service": "^3.0.0-rc.3"`